# createTempFile throws "Permission denied" exception

Tags: android, eclipse

My app. fails on the line:

```
File temp = File.createTempFile(“mediaplayertmp”, “dat”);
```

throws `“Permission denied”` exception.

Why could this occur?
It sounds like I need to change some kind of Java setting to designate a “`remp`” folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's probably that you don't have sufficient permissions to write to an external storage directory. I don't know that `createTempFile` requires this (I would think it would be on internal storage, but don't know that), but I would suggest adding the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your manifest, like so:

```
<manifest...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added that line to AndroidManifest.xml so that it now has two elements <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ; However, it does not change the application error. Do I have the change correct?

Comment: Update: Changing to the alternative signature for this call: File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat", this.getCacheDir()); works!

Comment: Ah okay! Glad you figured it out, I wasn't sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. For me it turned out the problem was that I had my Android device plugged into my PC via USB while I was developing, and the SD card is locked when it is mounted by another device. Once I unplugged the device, it worked fine. You can also tell the device not to mount the SD card when plugged in.

Answer (score 2):

Since AFAIK the default temp file location as configured by `java.io.tmpdir` is `/sdcard`, you'll need to add the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission to your manifest.